# google plus +1 button is grayed out, after updating google play service to version 4.0.33

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus-one

google plus +1 button is grayed out, after updating google play service to version 4.0.33, it gives "connection failed" error which status code is "INTERNAL_ERROR". A/c to new Google plus
service logging is necessary.

Comment: You don't need to fix this issue its and issue in the library only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It seems they still have not fixed the issue.